# Self argument in Scala

Tags: scala

This example is from one of the Scala books:

```
trait IO { self =>
  def run: Unit
  def ++(io: IO): IO = new IO {
    def run = { self.run; io.run }
  } 
}

object IO {
  def empty: IO = new IO { def run = () }
}
```

The explanation given in the book is as follows:

The self argument lets us refer to this object as self instead of this.

What would that statement mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`self` is just an alias to `this` in the object in which it is declared, and it can be any valid identifier (but not `this`, otherwise no alias is made). So `self` can be used to reference `this` from an outer object from within an inner object, where `this` would otherwise mean something different. Perhaps this example will clear things up:

```
trait Outer { self =>
    val a = 1

    def thisA = this.a // this refers to an instance of Outer
    def selfA = self.a // self is just an alias for this (instance of Outer)

    object Inner {
        val a = 2

        def thisA = this.a // this refers to an instance of Inner (this object)
        def selfA = self.a // self is still an alias for this (instance of Outer)
    }

}

object Outer extends Outer

Outer.a // 1
Outer.thisA // 1
Outer.selfA // 1

Outer.Inner.a // 2
Outer.Inner.thisA // 2
Outer.Inner.selfA // 1 *** From `Outer`
```

Comment: I get it now, self is not a keyword, just an alias! The alias name self is just confusing! Makes it feel like it is a keyword.